# Returning elements with php functions

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables, pointers

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
    $elements = array();

    function getElementByName($name) {
        foreach($this->elements as $elm) {
            if ($elm->name == $name) {
                return $elm;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the following code to modify the element of my array:

```
$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->getElementByName('foo1')->active = true;
```

Instead, when running my code, the `active` property of `$elements['foo1']` is still false as it was before calling getElementByName

I think that the function makes a "copy" of the element, how can I get the real element of the array, so that when I modify it, and then access it in the array, its values have changed?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior: http://codepad.org/7RFtib1d

Comment: You assume right. But note that PHP since version 5 should pass objects by reference anyway. Are you still running PHP 4?

Comment: @knittl PHP 4.4.9 will throw `unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Return a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) to it (notice the **&**):

```
function &getElementByName($name) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a reference to the element:

```
function &getElementByName($name) { // & returns by reference
    foreach($this->elements as $elm) {
        if ($elm->name == $name) {
            return $elm;
        }
    }
}
```

Starting with PHP 5 objects are [passed by reference](http://php.net/oop5.references) by default.

Comment: Actually, object references are passed by value.